# Assertion error polling from inside a new thread in ZeroMQ (JeroMQ)

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

I have code that looks like this:

```
public void handleRequests() {
    ZMQ.Poller items = new ZMQ.Poller(1);
    items.register(clientEndpoint, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        byte[] message;
        items.poll();  // this is the line that throws exception.
        if (items.pollin(0)) {
            message = clientEndpoint.recv(0);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when i call it directly:

```
foo.handleRequests();
```

but it fails regularly with assertion errors if it is run in a new thread:

```
final Runnable listener = worldviewServer::handleRequests;
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(listener);
```

The stack trace I get is shown below:

```
Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-1" java.lang.AssertionError
at zmq.Mailbox.recv(Mailbox.java:113)
at zmq.SocketBase.process_commands(SocketBase.java:820)
at zmq.SocketBase.getsockopt(SocketBase.java:258)
at zmq.PollItem.readyOps(PollItem.java:107)
at zmq.ZMQ.zmq_poll(ZMQ.java:708)
at zmq.ZMQ.zmq_poll(ZMQ.java:600)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Poller.poll(ZMQ.java:1618)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Poller.poll(ZMQ.java:1592)
at com.tracelink.worldview.server.Head.handleRequests(Head.java:68)
at com.tracelink.worldview.server.WorldviewServer.handleRequests(WorldviewServer.java:236)
at com.tracelink.worldview.server.fsm.EnablingAction$$Lambda$12/404648734.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using Java 8 with JeroMQ 0.3.5-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

ZMQ sockets are not threadsafe.  You have some limited ability to create a socket in one thread and then use it in another, but I'm guessing that the unseen code will branch off into multiple threads all attempting to use the socket at the same time.  That's a ZMQ no-no.  Generally, you should be creating sockets in the threads they'll be used in.

ZMQ contexts *are* threadsafe.

Comment: The attempts were all sequential, but I suppose it could be a problem down the road.  I would have multiple clients sending messages to the server over tcp, but not have multiple threads on the server write to the socket directly. The problem is that i need a server management layer above the req/reply layer, and can't have the server management code block while the socket is in the polling loop. I don't see a way to do that without starting the socket in a separate thread.

Comment: Word from ZMQ founders is that you must execute a full memory barrier between threads when handing off a socket from one thread to another, and only one thread can "own" a socket at a time. What you'll typically do if you want a thread that is completely dedicated to receiving and/or sending messages is create a second socket pair between that thread and your main thread. The 1st thread acts as a proxy, and your main thread just checks periodically for new messages in a non-blocking way.